# Establish Windows Phone 7 p2p connection to Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, p2p, windows-8

I would like to create multiplayer game that doesn't require Internet connection where Windows Phone 7 devices are clients and Windows 8 tablet is act as a server

Is it possible to establish peer-to-peer WiFi connection between several Windows Phone 7 applications and one Windows 8 application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows 8, but you can definitively use peer-to-peer between Windows Phone devices, and/or between a device and Windows 7.

Comment: Thx for quick answer. Peer-to-peer between Windows Phone 7 is only possible if they are in one network. Can a Windows 8 share a WiFi to other devices?... Even if it can, how to establish connection not only between WP7 devices but also for W8.

Comment: No, p2p also works just fine on different networks (over the internet). I don't really see the issue here, any device that's connected to a network, or the internet, can do peer to peer communication with each other.

Comment: Mmm... How do you connect WP7 devices without a server? WP7 device doesn't have static IP or something else to connect to it. I think it possible only with a multicast query, so they must be on the same network. But the question was different: requirement is defined as next - there is no Internet connection on ANY device